# Adding a script for post archive on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to run this code below on a post archive. And won't affect the other post in the archive?

You can check it here: https://pna-manufacturing.staging.tempurl.host/projects/

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.slick-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        var $sliderTitle = $('.slider-title');

        if (currentSlide === 0) {
            $sliderTitle.addClass('overlay-slider');
        } else {
            $sliderTitle.removeClass('overlay-slider');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

I am trying to get the dynamic ID of the post but this does not work well.
If this is not possible I may  have to individually run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add this script only on a specific post type's archive page, you can modify the function you provided as follows:

you can use the is_post_type_archive() function Like:

```
function add_custom_script() {
    // Check if it's the archive page for 'project' post type
    if (is_post_type_archive('project')) {
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.slick-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
                var $sliderTitle = $('.slider-title');

                if (currentSlide === 0) {
                    $sliderTitle.addClass('overlay-slider');
                } else {
                    $sliderTitle.removeClass('overlay-slider');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_script');
```

**Updated Answer**

The issue is that your JavaScript code is selecting all elements with the class slick-slider and slider-title, and applying the same logic to all of them, regardless of the actual active slide of a specific slider in a specific post. What you can do is to ensure the JavaScript only applies to the slick-slider and slider-title of a specific post.

Assuming that each post's slider is wrapped in an element that has a unique ID (or class) related to the post, such as post-123:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.post').each(function() {
        var $post = $(this);
        var $slickSlider = $post.find('.slick-slider');
        var $sliderTitle = $post.find('.slider-title');

        $slickSlider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
            if (currentSlide === 0) {
                $sliderTitle.addClass('overlay-slider');
            } else {
                $sliderTitle.removeClass('overlay-slider');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That is right as well. However, the problem is the Jquery code I created. 

What is showing on the post archive are sliders of the same custom post. 

The Jquery code adds a class on the specific element if slider 1 is active. 
But this adds the class to the other post in the archive as well. It should only add the class on that specific archive. Not sure on how can I dynamically get the post id to add it on the script or It should show on the CSS output

Comment: Thank you that gave me the idea that worked very well. I only updated the class

 $('.grid-item-cont').each(function() and this worked perfectly